# Direct an Application's Audio to Specific Monitor / Speakers

Tags: windows-7, audio, multiple-monitors, speakers

I have 2 monitors, both with built in speakers and am using Windows 7 Home Premium.

I've plugged the audio for one into `Front Speaker Out` and the other into `Rear Speaker Out`. I also have a front panel output, for headphones.

Ideally i'd like applications displayed on a monitor to output sound to that monitor. Failing that i'd like certain applications to use `Rear Speaker Out` as opposed to the normal, `Front Speaker Out`.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are SOL on this one.

AFAIK, Microsoft does not publish public APIs that allow you to programatically redirect the sound of another program.

Each program, however, can redirect its own sound.

I know there is code out there that lets you access the nonpublic APIs. I wouldn't say any I've seen so far is "user friendly."

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i was starting to think that what i'm hoping for is impossible due to lack of answers. I can't be the only one who would like this though. Dual monitors are fairly common among a fair few people. Will leave this open for a few more days then accept unless someone has something better.

Comment: While dual monitors are very common according to Microsoft, switching between audio sources, let alone monitors attached to speakers is very uncommon.